# vim install on freebsd has taken 5 hours and counting

Tags: vim, software-installation, freebsd, amazon-ec2

Ok, so installed [portmaster](http://www.freshports.org/ports-mgmt/portmaster) and I'm trying with it, I'm hoping it won't take time.

---

So I've been up all night and my vim installation is still going on.

I have an amazon ec2 freebsd server setup. I was hoping to setup jails, which took 4-5 hours to `make world` then crashed.

I got that fixed and realized I didn't have vim. I google and found [this article](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-install-vim-text-editor-under-freebsd/).

So like a moron I did a make install for **vim** instead of **vim-lite** like the article says. It has been 5 hours or so and it's still going on and I have no clue what to do. It also keeps coming up with different prompts which I have to answer to continue.

1. If I kill this installation, can I just start from scratch and install vim-lite? Will my system will be ok? Will it take this long again?
2. Should I wait? I can't stay up any longer though to keep pressing enter!

---

Background: On EC2 freebsd doesn't come with ports installed at all. So I installed it, took some time. Other than that, since I did `make install clean` inside `/usr/ports/editors/vim/` it has just been spitting at my screen non-stop.

Comment: To rebuild everything from scratch certainly will take a lot of time (why do that in the first place?), but building vim should never take that long (unless it has to build a _lot_ or requirements before). Something is _very wrong. What does `ps` say, what is running (if anything) right now? Can't you find a ready-to-install version somewhere?

Comment: I don't think anything is wrong - vim has a huge list of build dependencies, so it will take a long time to complete. It pulls in Xorg, atk, glibc, etc., as none of these deps is installed in FreeBSD as part of the base system. In my experience, software builds on EC2 can be quite slow anyway.

Comment: yea true it does. But why can't I just download the binary. I switched to portmaster and it still takes so long!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is perfectly safe to stop the build. If the system has already installed some of the dependencies, you can simply uninstall them, using a tool like `ports-mgmt/pkg_cutleaves`. You can then start again with the `editors/vim-lite` port, which has a much smaller list of dependencies (only `gettext` and `libiconv`, instead of the 72 dependencies for the full `editors/vim` port!), so should build much more quickly.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. (1) Can I use portmaster to just get the binary, intead of building it all. (2) Of all things, my laptop power was disconnected while I was away during the vim installation and now when I tried vim-lite it says it conflicts with vim, so I'm giving vim a shot again.

Comment: Ok. Done, It got over in about 20 mins! :D

Comment: `portmaster` is able to fetch and install prebuilt packages - use the `-P` option. The `portmaster` manpage contains a lot of detail.

Comment: Hm Alright I shall take a look at it. I basically just want a jail with perl in it up and running. Quick **final** question, If I do `portmaster -y some_dir;portmaster -y some_other_dir;portmaster -y third_dir`. I should be able to start a couple of installs like this and leave it overnight or something?

Comment: If you arrange for them to run consecutively, yes - that should work just fine. Be careful of running multiple instances of `portmaster` in parallel, though - there's a chance that they'll both try to download and install the same port at the same time, with unspecified results!